# mshtml.dll not found by installshield

Tags: c#, installshield, gac

note: On my computer I've had both VS2010, VS2012 and now I have VS2013 installed.

In my c# project we use the `Microsoft.mshtml.dll` file. Now there are no problems during development, but when I'm about to create my Setup with Installsheild LE it complains that it can't find the file `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Common\Microsoft.mshtml.dll`. And looking at my disk that's correct, there are no such file.

Now looking in the `Add reference` view the tool-tip for that dll says the same path but with 10.0 instead of 11.0. And that file actually exist.

I have also looked in my 12.0 folder, and also there the dll exist.

I'm guessing that something is messed up in my GAC (where it's also is located) or some other thing that makes it look in the wrong place. But I can't figure out where and what.

(I have tried to just copy the file from the 12.0 folder to the 11.0 folder, and that actually works. However that seem a little wrong in some way.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051604/microsoft-mshtml-dll-redistribution-issues

Comment: Although this gave me some insight in what PIA is and how they work, it shed no lights on why my InstallShield looks in a old VS folder, nor did it help to set the `Embed interop Types`. That actually broke my build instead. I think I'll go with my ugly copy for now...